# How to show datatable pagination like last prev current_page next last?

Tags: datatable, datatables

If user is on first page it has to show like
<< < 1 > >>
 and if he click on next then it show like
<< < 2 > >>

Answer (score 0):

This will customize the pagination as per your specification:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
      "pagingType": "full",
      "language": {
        "paginate": {
          "first":      "<<",
          "last":       ">>",
          "next":       ">",
          "previous":   "<"
        }
      },
      "initComplete": function() {
        $( "<span>1</span>" ).insertAfter( "a.paginate_button.previous" );
      }
    });

    myTable.on( 'draw', function () {
      var pg = myTable.page.info().page +1;
      $( "<span>" + pg + "</span>" ).insertAfter( "a.paginate_button.previous" );
    } );

  } );

</script>
```

When the table is first initialized, it uses a hard-coded "1" for the page number. For re-draws (e.g. when you filter the data or move between pages), it gets the current page number dynamically.

You can read about the various options in the DataTables documentation:

[paging types](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html)

[pagination language](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language)

[initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)

[page info](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info())